# Azure Kusto Data Explorer - invoking multiple management queries at once

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to run multiple [alter-column](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/alter-column) commands at once (to save some time).

For example, I have these 2 commands:

```
.alter column e53b2c81_eb5c_45e4_9e5e_333332211111.name policy encoding type='identifier'

.alter column e53b2c81_eb5c_45e4_9e5e_333332211111.doc policy encoding type='bigobject'
```

And running them separately works fine. but I want to invoke them together. So I tried something like:

```
.alter column e53b2c81_eb5c_45e4_9e5e_333332211111.name policy encoding type='identifier';
.alter column e53b2c81_eb5c_45e4_9e5e_333332211111.doc policy encoding type='bigobject';
```

But it didn't work.

Is there any way I can run them both together?

(Eventually, I want to avoid running this query for 1000+ tables for different fields. I much rather performing this task at once to avoid so many requests. I'll be running these commands through the Golang SDK).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could include all commands in a script, and use the [.execute database script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/execute-database-script) command to have them run by the service one after the other.

Please note that this does *not* run all commands in the script in a single transaction - commands are executed sequentially, in the order they appear in the input script.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like it only works when I use the DB name in each alter column command:
`.alter column ['DB_NAME'].e53b2c81_eb5c_45e4_9e5e_333332211111.name policy encoding ...`